# How to recreate this cut out effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, images, effects

In searching for themes for my personal blog, I stumbled upon the following design and I'm really curious about how the effect was created as I want to do something similar.

It appears to be some rough cut out with a fade and some smudging as well as combining a few images in an interesting way, but I have no idea how to pull it off in Photoshop or some other tool from the Adobe suite.

Here are 2 examples of the effect, which I can't find a specific name for:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I would be extremely grateful for any help or even a link to a tutorial if someone has seen something similar explained before :)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do this, the easiest way is probably to create a layer mask and use a rough chalk brush or something similar.

**My approach**

Do a rough cut with the polygonal lasso, or any tool of your choice.

[image: rough cut]

Add a layer mask to your layer. You find it in the bottom right corner. Then use a rough paintbrush with black color, to draw around the edge. An opacity arount 70% works good here.

[image]